# How to know the number of NAL unit in H.264 stream which represent a picture

Tags: c++, h.264, rtsp, libavcodec

I'm using cameras with an H.264 stream over RTSP decoded with avcodec. For most of the camera, each packet (NAL unit) received represent a complete frame (I Frame or frame) and when i decode it i obtain a frame each time.
But for another camera, a frame is split in many NAL unit of constant size, when i decode each packet, i don't got a frame for each packet.

I saw that there is a start and end flags in NAL unit. The end flags is never set, except for PPS or SPS. Nevertheless, I can detect start code, and tell every frame end when a new frame begin.

I would like to buffer every NAL unit, within a single frame before to send it to the decoder (this for recording feature and to minimize frame indexing).

Here an example (start_flags is 128 within NAL[1] byte)

```
NALU: 10 bytes: SPS, NAL[1]={0,64,0,2} // Start Frame 1
NALU: 5 bytes: PPS, NAL[1]={128,64,0,14}
NALU: 551 bytes: I-Frame, NAL[1]={128,0,0,8}
NALU: 531 bytes: I-Frame, NAL[1]={0,0,0,9}
NALU: 532 bytes: I-Frame, NAL[1]={0,0,0,4}
NALU: 517 bytes: I-Frame, NAL[1]={0,0,0,7}
NALU: 533 bytes: I-Frame, NAL[1]={0,0,0,3}
NALU: 621 bytes: I-Frame, NAL[1]={0,0,0,3}
NALU: 586 bytes: I-Frame, NAL[1]={0,0,0,1}
NALU: 520 bytes: I-Frame, NAL[1]={0,0,0,1}
NALU: 507 bytes: I-Frame, NAL[1]={0,0,0,1}
NALU: 508 bytes: I-Frame, NAL[1]={0,0,0,1}
NALU: 531 bytes: I-Frame, NAL[1]={0,0,0,0}
NALU: 558 bytes: I-Frame, NAL[1]={0,0,0,0}
NALU: 49 bytes: I-Frame, NAL[1]={0,0,0,0} // Start Frame 2 + END Frame 1
NALU: 253 bytes: Frame, NAL[1]={128,0,0,26} // Start Frame 3 + END Frame 2
// Frame 2 start so we can record/decode Frame 1
NALU: 510 bytes: Frame, NAL[1]={128,0,0,26}
// Frame 3 start so we can record/decode Frame 2
NALU: 506 bytes: Frame, NAL[1]={0,0,0,1}
NALU: 267 bytes: Frame, NAL[1]={0,0,0,0} // Start Frame 4 + END Frame 3
NALU: 535 bytes: Frame, NAL[1]={128,0,0,26}
// Frame 4 start so we can record/decode Frame 3
NALU: 527 bytes: Frame, NAL[1]={0,0,0,4}
NALU: 509 bytes: Frame, NAL[1]={0,0,0,3}
NALU: 508 bytes: Frame, NAL[1]={0,0,0,1}
NALU: 519 bytes: Frame, NAL[1]={0,0,0,0}
NALU: 327 bytes: Frame, NAL[1]={0,0,0,0} // END Frame 4
...
```

However, it seems i got some troubles with some streams. For stream where each NAL unit represent a frame, it seems if i decode frame only when the next start, the RTSP stream seems to drop some I-Frame. I think it's a synchronization problem due to the maybe due decoding time because the problem doesn't occurs is i decode frame when directly received.

Here the detail when I decode directly (every thing works correctly):

```
NALU: 24 bytes: SPS, NAL[1]={0,64,0,13} // Start Frame 1
NALU: 4 bytes: PPS, NAL[1]={128,64,32,14}
NALU: 176124 bytes: Frame, NAL[1]={128,0,0,8}
// Decode Frame 1 OK
NALU: 24 bytes: SPS, NAL[1]={0,64,0,13}  // Start Frame 2
NALU: 4 bytes: PPS, NAL[1]={128,64,32,14}
NALU: 175605 bytes: I-Frame, NAL[1]={128,0,0,8}
// Decode Frame 2 OK
NALU: 38777 bytes: Frame, NAL[1]={128,0,0,26} // Start Frame 3
// Decode Frame 3 OK
NALU: 32188 bytes: Frame, NAL[1]={128,0,0,26} // Start Frame 4
// Decode Frame 4 OK
NALU: 24 bytes: SPS, NAL[1]={0,64,0,13} // Start Frame 5
NALU: 4 bytes: PPS, NAL[1]={128,64,32,14}
NALU: 175975 bytes: I-Frame, NAL[1]={128,0,0,8}
// Decode Frame 5 OK
NALU: 41681 bytes: Frame, NAL[1]={128,0,0,26} // Start Frame 6
// Decode Frame 6 OK
```

Here the detail when I decode after each frame start (some frame are not decoded):

```
NALU: 24 bytes: NAL[0]={0,3,7}, NAL[1]={0,64,0,13} // Start frame 1
NALU: 4 bytes: NAL[0]={0,3,8}, NAL[1]={128,64,32,14}
NALU: 177827 bytes: NAL[0]={0,3,1}, NAL[1]={128,0,0,8}
NALU: 24 bytes: NAL[0]={0,3,7}, NAL[1]={0,64,0,13} // Start frame 2 + End frame 1
// Decode Frame 1 OK
NALU: 4 bytes: NAL[0]={0,3,8}, NAL[1]={128,64,32,14}
NALU: 43304 bytes: NAL[0]={0,3,1}, NAL[1]={128,0,0,26}
NALU: 39115 bytes: NAL[0]={0,3,1}, NAL[1]={128,0,0,26} // Start frame 3 + End frame 2
// Decode Frame 2 OK
NALU: 24 bytes: NAL[0]={0,3,7}, NAL[1]={0,64,0,13} // Start frame 4 + End frame 3
// Decode Frame 3 OK
NALU: 4 bytes: NAL[0]={0,3,8}, NAL[1]={128,64,32,14} 
NALU: 49200 bytes: NAL[0]={0,3,1}, NAL[1]={128,0,0,26}
NALU: 41002 bytes: NAL[0]={0,3,1}, NAL[1]={128,0,0,26}  // Start frame 5 + End frame 4
// Decode Frame 4 failed
 NALU: 39581 bytes: NAL[0]={0,3,1}, NAL[1]={128,0,0,26}
// Decode Frame 5 failed
```

It's like if some frame are dropped by the RTSP stream (I-Frame)

So my questions are:

- Do you think RTPS drop some frames?
- Is H.264 decoder expect frame arriving within a delay to be decoded properly, respecting some timecode or something like that?
- How can I detect the NAL unit is the last of the picture, instead of waiting the start of the next one.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

First off, there is no "end flag". Only start codes for annex B and NALU size for other formats (I believe RTP uses annex B). What you are calling a frame, in H.264, is called an access unit. For each access unit non Video coding layer (non-VCL) NALUS optionally precede VCL nalus. So to determine if you have all the VCL Nalus, you must parse each NALU to determine what macroblocks are encoded into the slice. By using data you received parsed form the SPS, you can determine how may macroblocks there are per frame. Then once you have received all the macroblocks, you can decode the frame.

Comment: Thank you. This is more clear for me now. ;). I will try to deal with that. And I let you know if i need for information.

Comment: Hi, i tried to deal with your information. I succeed to parse the SPS, and getting the size in macroblock. I'm also able to get address of the first macroblock in slice. Nevertheless, i don't understand how i can know that i got all macroblock. If i understand well, the last macroblock may not be send (if not modified). Should i parse also all macro block? This seems to be heavy for what i really need. Thanks in advance.